# how to add an input parameter to a form using jQuery

Tags: jquery

```
 $('form').submit(function(){
            this.action="http://www.sitename.com/post";
            return false;
        });
```

having altered the action attribute of the form ,i want to add one more input parameter to it how do i do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just append an input element:

```
$('form').append('<input type="hidden" name="newParam" value="Hello" />');
```

Comment: i tried that but i can't see the hidden parameter in the string produced by form.serialize() .

Comment: @Bunny Rabbit: Did you make sure the element had the `name` attribute?  Maybe you could post the whole code that you tried?